# Problems with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: no update/upgrade possible

Tags: upgrade, package-management, software-center

please check this and give me some hints.

### I wanna to upgrade my Ubuntu14 to 16. But:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 325, in _process_transaction
    self._apply_changes(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/pkcompat.py", line 3157, in _apply_changes
    install_range)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1151, in _apply_changes
    with self._frozen_status():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1175, in _frozen_status
    frozen_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="aptdaemon-frozen-status")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 434, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/aptdaemon-frozen-statusrx8ib9k6'
```

--
Unable to lock-crash report

[image: crash report ubuntu 14.04]

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiYuf.jpg)

Comment: Your disk is full.

Comment: Please share the output of "df -h /tmp"; first output complains no space left in "/tmp/aptdaemon-frozen-statusrx8ib9k6"

Comment: Here is it: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        60G   20G   37G  36% /

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the error reports that your disk space is full. You should either free disk by deleting or moving files out of `/` partition. You can also expand the partition by using partitioning tools like `gparted`.

Comment: I do have about 60GB free on the partition...

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of gparted.

Comment: There are more messages: 1. "Unable to get exclusive lock"; 2. "...another application (like apt-get or aptitude) is already running".

Comment: Try restarting your system and do it again.

Comment: gparted: unable to insert the screenshot in the comment...

Comment: Edit the question and post it in the question

Comment: snapshot added...Label: "gparted"